bcrypt.compare always returns false despite correct password in Node.js
I'm implementing a login functionality using Node.js, bcrypt, and Express. Even when I input the correct password, bcrypt.compare returns false. I suspect there's an issue with how the passwords are hashed or stored in my database.
Here is my setup:
I have required all the essentials
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const userModel = require("./models/user"); // Mongoose model
const { body, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

Registration Endpoint:
This is where I hash and save the password during user registration.
router.post(


"/register",
  body("email").trim().isEmail().isLength({ min: 10 }),
  body("password").trim().isLength({ min: 5 }),
  body("username").trim().isLength({ min: 3 }),
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
  return res.status(400).json({
    errors: errors.array(),
    message: "invalid data",
  });
}

const { email, username, password } = req.body;

console.log(password);

const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

const newUser = await userModel.create({
  email,
  username,
  password: hashPassword,
});

res.json(newUser);


 }

);

Login Endpoint:
Here is the code for verifying the password during login:
router.post(


"/login",
  body("username").trim().isLength({ min: 3 }),
  body("password").trim().isLength({ min: 5 }),
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
  return res.status(400).json({
    error: errors.array(),
    message: "invalid data",
  });
}

const { username, password } = req.body;

const user = await userModel.findOne({
  username: username,
});

console.log(user);

if (!user) {
  return res.status(400).json({
    message: "username",
  });
}

console.log(password, user.password, username);

const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

console.log(isMatch);

if (!isMatch) {
  return res.status(400).json({
    message: " password is incorrect",
  });
}

My Observations:
1)The username is successfully retrieved from the database.
2)The password input matches what was entered during registration, but bcrypt.compare(password, user.password) still returns false
3)Provided password matches what I typed.
4)Stored hash looks like a valid bcrypt hash.
5)isMatch is always false.

Are there c mistakes in using bcrypt.compare that I might have overlooked?

Try trimming the password before hashing it: const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password.trim(), user.password);
OR
Is there any chance that you're using hashing login in your User Model and in API too? This will cause double hashing and that too can lead to isMatch always being false.
